# Can anyone provide a working example of AudioFileStreamSeek for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, audio, streaming

I find Apple's documentation quite limited on AudioFileStreamSeek and I cannot find any examples of actual usage anywhere. I have a working streaming audio player, but I just can't seem to get AudioFileStreamSeek to work as advertised...

Any help tips or a little example would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Let me know if you find a solution. Am still stuck!

Answer (score 2):

I am told this works:

```
AudioQueueStop(audioQueue, true);
UInt32 flags = 0;
err = AudioFileStreamParseBytes(audioFileStream, length, bytes,
                                kAudioFileStreamParseFlag_Discontinuity);

OSStatus status = AudioFileStreamSeek(audioFileStream, framePacket.mPacket, 
                                      &currentOffset, &flags);
NSLog(@"Setting next byte offset to: %qi, flags: %d", (long long)currentOffset, flags);

// then read data from the new offset set by AudioFileStreamSeek
[fileHandle seekToFileOffset:currentOffset];
NSData* data = "" readDataOfLength:4096];

flags = kAudioFileStreamParseFlag_Discontinuity;
status = AudioFileStreamParseBytes( stream, [data length], [data bytes], flags);
if (status != noErr)
{
    NSLog(@"Error parsing bytes: %d", status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Unless I'm mistaken, this is only available in the 3.0 SDK, and therefore under NDA. Maybe you should take this to the [Apple Beta forums](https://devforums.apple.com/)?</s>

I stand corrected. AudioFileStreamSeek doesn't show up if you do a search in the online 2.2.1 documentation. You have to manually dig into the docs to find it.

Comment: No. I just check the XCode docs for AudioFileStreamSeek and it says: 

Available in iPhone OS 2.0 and later.

Comment: I stand corrected. AudioFileStreamSeek doesn't show up if you do a search in the online 2.2.1 documentation. You have to manually dig into the docs to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add the data offset (kAudioFileStreamProperty_DataOffset) to the byte offset returned by AudioFileStreamSeek. The return value is an offset into the audio data and ignores the data offset.

It's also a good idea to stop and then re-start the AudioQueue before/after seeking.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gallagher uses `AudioFileStreamSeek` in his example ["Streaming and playing an MP3 stream"](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html).

Look at Matt's code `AudioStreamer.m`:

```
SInt64 seekPacket = floor(newSeekTime / packetDuration);
err = AudioFileStreamSeek(audioFileStream, seekPacket, &packetAlignedByteOffset, &ioFlags);
```

Comment: The critical thing according to his notes is that you have to use `kAudioFileStreamParseFlag_Discontinuity` in the flags to the next call to ParseBytes, which isn't documented as a requirement, but is in many ways logical...